# Accessing a pointer in a struct through a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So I've been looking over structs while reading abut linked lists and came across a thought.

> How do I properly access a pointer in a struct using a pointer to the struct?

For example I have a declaration of a struct as such:

```
typedef struct Sample{
    int x;
    int *y;
} Sample;

Sample test, *pter;  // Declare the struct and a pointer to it.
pter = &test;
```

So now I have a pointer to the struct and I know I can access the data in `int x` like this: `pter->x` and that is the same as this. However I'm having trouble choosing/figuring out how to access `*y` through the pointer.

One of my friends say I should do it like this: `*pter->y`, however I'm thinking that it would make more sense to do it as such: `pter->*y`. Which is the right/only/proper/correct way to do it? Would both of them work perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For value of `y` use `pter->y`, and for value stored at  `y` use `*pter->y` (that is equivalent to `*(pter->y)` ).

Note: [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) of `->` operator is higher then `*` Dereference operator that is why  `*pter->y` == `*(pter->y)`

Edit: on the basis of comment.

The expression `pter-> *y` should be a syntax error as it can't be a valid expression because of following reasons.

1. If `*` is interpreated as unary dereference operator and applied on `y`, then `y` is unknown variable name(without `pter`).
2. If `*` is treated as  as multiplication operator then `->` can't appear before `*`.

So in both way it is compilation produces error.

Comment: I don't/can't seem to understand the concept of precedence and how it works here. Why can't/shouldn't it be: `pter>*y`?

Comment: See `pter-> *y` then  (1) `*` is if applied on `y` then `y` is unknown (without `pter`) (2) if `*` uses as multiplication operator then `->` can't appear before `*` So in both way it is compilation error.

Comment: @Link Got it or should I explain in answer.

Comment: Well, I suggest editing the answer for posterity, and easier to read later. But I'll be accepting the answer.

Comment: @Link I test [here](http://codepad.org/icRggsqe#line-12) It gives `'error: expected identifier before '*' token'` so in your expression `*` interpreted as `*` by gcc compiler as is accept a valid operand-identifier before `*` (according to error message). Note: producing error message may be different at different compilers. Understand Language standards tells what is valid syntax.  But don't says any thing about what should be compiler message. It is upto the compiler (a better compiler gives better message). Although error message should be derived from grammar used to describing syntax.

Comment: @Link Do you understand shift-reduce parser?